# JDialog without default buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jdialog

I'm opening a JDialog like this:

```
    public JPanel buildAddFrame(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contentPanel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel topButtonBar = new JPanel();
        topButtonBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topButtonBar, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JTextField text = new JTextField("Hello there.");
        topButtonBar.add(text);

        contentPanel.add(topButtonBar);

        return contentPanel;
    }

    public void buttonPressed(){
        JOptionPane addDialog = new JOptionPane(buildAddFrame());
        JDialog dialog = addDialog.createDialog(this, "Test dialog");
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("dialog closed.");
    }
```

So when someone presses a button on my main form, the dialog pops up and asks for input in a variety of controls (right now only a text field to start). I'm having trouble with 2 things though:

1: There is an "OK" button at the bottom that the user can click to close the dialog, though I don't want this. I want to make my own buttons and position them and stuff, so is there a way to disable this default button and just use my own from the JPanel I create?

2: Is there a way to access the controls in my dialog via `dialog.*` or `addDialog.*` in `buttonPressed()`? I guess I could just send all the content of the controls to some variables when the submit button is pressed, though that seems a bit lazy.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Just create your own JDialog without a JOptionPane.  Add the buttons to your JPanel, and add the JPanel to a JDialog.  2.  Write getters for all the values you want to retrieve after the user presses the OK (or whatever) button.  If there are a lot of values, create a model class with the values, and retrieve an instance of the model class.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType, Icon icon, Object[] options)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#JOptionPane(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[])) for starters, if that's not enough, you'll need to roll your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't use JOptionPane.  Create a JDialog directly and then add a JPanel to it with your own controls laid out as desired.

2) You could assess the controls that you add to your JPanel directly.

For example:

```
public void buttonPressed(){
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    panel.add(tf);
    JButton ok = new JButton("ok");
    panel.add(ok);
    dialog.add(panel);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("dialog closed. tf=" + tf.getText());
}
```

Of course this will not look right, you need to use a layout manager.  I suggest using NetBeans to build your forms.  This way you can customize the JDialog much easier.

Comment: For some reason when I remove the JOptionPane, the program doesn't halt at `dialog.setVisible(true)` anymore. Even copy-pasting your code into my program, the System.out.println is called as soon as the dialog opens...

Comment: Well, my example will not work exactly.  The ok button needs to call dialog.dispose() somehow.  It's best to create your own class that extends JDialog and build as needed.

Comment: @Nathan You need to specify that the dialog be made modal, see the Java docs for details. You can do this either via the constructor or via the setModal method

Comment: 1- Generally, it's a bad idea to extend directly from top level containers, it locks you into a single use-case which reduces your ability to reuse the UI or extend it in the future; 2- for new developers, I'd recommend learning to hand code the UI to start with, it gives a greater understanding of the overall api and layout managers in particular, this will generate a greater appreciation for when and how form editors can be used to make life easier. Form editors also make a mess of the code, making it difficult to modify to any extend - but that's just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at public [`JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType, Icon icon, Object[] options)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html%23JOptionPane(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) which will allow you to customise the options (or buttons) that are displayed by the dialog.

If this isn't sufficient enough for you, you'll need to roll your own, this is basically the same as you would do for creating a `JFrame`, expect you would use a `JDialog`